# GL_ALPHA, GL_LUMINANCE

Tags: opengl, textures, formats

I'm trying to bind a texture that I want to interpret as either Alpha, Luminance or Intensity.  I'm using OpenGL 4.0.  I can bind them as GL_RED OK with no problems, i.e. :

```
glTexImage2D(   GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                i,
                GL_RED,
                mipSizeX,
                mipSizeY,
                0,
                GL_RED, 
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                nullptr);
```

However whenever I try to bind as GL_ALPHA, GL_LUMINANCE or GL_INTENSITY, I get an error 1280.  Are those formats deprecated with GL 4.0, or am I doing something wrong?  E.g. this fails:

```
glTexImage2D(   GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                i,
                GL_ALPHA8
                mipSizeX,
                mipSizeY,
                0,
                GL_ALPHA, 
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                nullptr);
```

EDIT: Ok as these formats are deprecated, [this page](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) contains tables showing what the valid formats actually are.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Are those formats deprecated with GL 4.0

Yes, they are.